# MikTeX initexmf pdflatex error (initexmf --dump=pdflatex)

Tags: miktex, initex

I use Windows 10 21H1 and MikTeX (basic-miktex-21.12-x64.exe). I just installed it and get the following problem* in the miktex-makefmt.log file after I do this on the command line:

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex
```

this opens a file where I put something along the line:

```
main_memory = 100000000
```

and than save it, close the window and do this on the command line:

```
initexmf --dump=pdflatex
```

Btw. this has always worked in the past (other laptops) for me, so I don't think there is any problem with it.

- Even I can see the FATAL Error line, but I don't know what to do...:

```
2022-02-05 17:37:55,689+0100 INFO  miktex-makefmt - this process (10224) started by 'initexmf' with command line: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2022-02-05 17:37:55,700+0100 INFO  makefmt - found input file: C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\pdflatex.ini
2022-02-05 17:37:55,705+0100 INFO  makefmt - Creating the pdflatex format file...
2022-02-05 17:37:55,723+0100 INFO  makefmt - Running miktex-pdftex.exe...
2022-02-05 17:37:55,723+0100 INFO  makefmt - running: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2022-02-05 17:37:55,724+0100 INFO  miktex-makefmt.core - start process: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2022-02-05 17:37:56,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - miktex-pdftex.exe failed on pdflatex.ini.
2022-02-05 17:37:56,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - miktex-pdftex.exe failed on pdflatex.ini.
2022-02-05 17:37:56,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Info: 
2022-02-05 17:37:56,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Source: 
2022-02-05 17:37:56,302+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Line: 0
2022-02-05 17:37:56,321+0100 INFO  miktex-makefmt - this process (10224) finishes with exit code 1
2022-02-05 17:37:56,321+0100 WARN  miktex-makefmt.core - still open: C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex\generic\config\pdftexconfig.tex
2022-02-05 17:37:56,321+0100 WARN  miktex-makefmt.core - still open: C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/config\pdftexconfig.tex.in
```

Edit 1: @UlrikeFischer yes I do have a anit-virus program: Kaspersky Total Security (but again I had this on all my previous laptops/pcs and it was never a problem)

Edit 2: This is the initexmf.log file with an ERROR line about 'Path' something... ^^:

```
2022-02-05 17:35:32,469+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:32,469+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (6136) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --rmfndb --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:32,469+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:32,469+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (6136) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:33,016+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:33,016+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (6340) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --update-fndb --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:33,032+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:33,047+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX)...
2022-02-05 17:35:33,047+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\MiKTeX)...
2022-02-05 17:35:33,063+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX)...
2022-02-05 17:35:35,937+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for MPM...
2022-02-05 17:35:38,595+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (6340) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:38,892+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:38,892+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (14388) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --force --mklinks --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:38,892+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:38,892+0100 INFO  initexmf - Collecting linked executables in target directory C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/bin/x64...
2022-02-05 17:35:38,923+0100 WARN  initexmf - The lualatex executable could not be found.
2022-02-05 17:35:41,360+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (14388) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:41,641+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:41,641+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (16456) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --mkmaps --mklangs --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:41,641+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:41,641+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def...
2022-02-05 17:35:41,720+0100 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --verbose --disable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2022-02-05 17:35:41,720+0100 INFO  initexmf.core - start process: mkfntmap --verbose --disable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2022-02-05 17:35:46,765+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (16456) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:47,062+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:47,062+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (14032) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --default-paper-size=A4 --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:47,062+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:47,093+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (14032) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:47,390+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:47,390+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (16328) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --set-config-value=[MPM]AutoInstall=1 --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:47,390+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:47,390+0100 INFO  initexmf - Setting config value: [MPM]AutoInstall=1
2022-02-05 17:35:47,437+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (16328) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:47,718+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:47,718+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (900) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --update-fndb --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:47,718+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:47,749+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX)...
2022-02-05 17:35:47,796+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\MiKTeX)...
2022-02-05 17:35:47,796+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX)...
2022-02-05 17:35:50,249+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for MPM...
2022-02-05 17:35:52,889+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (900) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:53,186+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:53,186+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (14896) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --register-shell-file-types --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:53,186+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:53,186+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .asy
2022-02-05 17:35:53,186+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .bib
2022-02-05 17:35:53,186+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .cls
2022-02-05 17:35:53,186+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .dtx
2022-02-05 17:35:53,186+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .dvi
2022-02-05 17:35:53,201+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .ltx
2022-02-05 17:35:53,201+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .pdf
2022-02-05 17:35:53,201+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .sty
2022-02-05 17:35:53,201+0100 INFO  initexmf - registering file extension: .tex
2022-02-05 17:35:53,248+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (14896) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:53,529+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:53,529+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (16540) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --modify-path --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:53,529+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:53,529+0100 ERROR initexmf.core - Setting new user PATH:
2022-02-05 17:35:53,529+0100 ERROR initexmf.core - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%CLion%;%PyCharm%;C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\
2022-02-05 17:35:53,607+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (16540) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:35:53,889+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:35:53,889+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (7812) started by 'basic-miktex-21.12-x64' with command line: initexmf --report --log-file=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\uninst.log --disable-installer --verbose
2022-02-05 17:35:53,889+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:35:53,904+0100 ERROR initexmf.core - Something is wrong with the PATH:
2022-02-05 17:35:53,904+0100 ERROR initexmf.core - C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.1.3\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\bin;C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
2022-02-05 17:35:53,920+0100 ERROR initexmf.core - Something is wrong with the PATH:
2022-02-05 17:35:53,920+0100 ERROR initexmf.core - C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.1.3\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\bin;C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
2022-02-05 17:35:53,982+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (7812) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:37:24,515+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:37:24,515+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (15952) started by 'cmd' with command line: initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex
2022-02-05 17:37:24,515+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:37:24,515+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating config file: C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\miktex\config\pdflatex.ini...
2022-02-05 17:37:24,546+0100 INFO  initexmf.core - start process: notepad.exe C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\miktex/config\pdflatex.ini
2022-02-05 17:37:24,627+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (15952) finishes with exit code 0
2022-02-05 17:37:55,169+0100 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 4.7 (MiKTeX 21.12)
2022-02-05 17:37:55,170+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (15180) started by 'cmd' with command line: initexmf --dump=pdflatex
2022-02-05 17:37:55,170+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2022-02-05 17:37:55,175+0100 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2022-02-05 17:37:55,176+0100 INFO  initexmf.core - start process: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2022-02-05 17:37:56,331+0100 ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2022-02-05-173756.out'
2022-02-05 17:37:56,332+0100 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2022-02-05 17:37:56,332+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1"
2022-02-05 17:37:56,332+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: 
2022-02-05 17:37:56,332+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 0
2022-02-05 17:37:56,334+0100 INFO  initexmf - this process (15180) finishes with exit code 1
```

Comment: well without knowing why the format failed it is difficult to help. Check the log file (it should be in `...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex`)  for a clue.  Do you have some virus protection which could interfere?

Comment: Try with a more little number  : `main_memory=12000000` works on my systeme

Comment: @ManuelCart that works... but why? This laptop now (newest dell xps 15) should be 'better' in any way so why must I reduce the number? But I guess that solved it ^^, thanks <3. Actually how is the max. number determined? Can I find it out somehow? :D

Comment: I don't know why there was a change but 12000000 seems to be the maximum see here : [link](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/discussions/1029)

Comment: @ManuelCart ty. It works now fine. :) How do I close this question...?